# Unable to implement Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

```
**MainActivity.java**

     facebookbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(fb.isSessionValid())
                    {
                        try {
                            fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                            updatebuttonimage();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"email"},new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FacebookError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                                editor.putString("access_token",fb.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",fb.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();
                                updatebuttonimage();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });

    private void updatebuttonimage()
        {

            if(fb.isSessionValid())
            {
                facebookbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.fblogout);
                pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

            }
            else
            {
                facebookbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.login);
            }

        }

**Logcat :**

12-12 10:28:59.843: W/dalvikvm(29773): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.hashCode(HttpConnection.java:314)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:302)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:73)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.example.facebook_integration.MainActivity.updatebuttonimage(MainActivity.java:140)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.example.facebook_integration.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:123)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.example.facebook_integration.MainActivity$1$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:106)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:345)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$11(Facebook.java:326)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.call(Facebook.java:304)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1302)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-12 10:28:59.867: E/AndroidRuntime(29773):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am able to connect to facebook. Once i login and return to my app, i should be able to see the image change and it is implemented in updatebuttonimage() method but it throws an NullPointerException and also that i have already called this method in onCreate() method but it did not throw it then. I am unable to figure out the issue.  Help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: Why are you calling uploadimage method after logout ? Do you thing after logout you will get valid session with accesstoken ?

Comment: @GrIsHu: it is not `uploadimage`, it is `updatebuttonimage` possibly to swap login/logout image on the button.

Comment: Thanks guys,will post the logcat..